# nerual networks: gpu vs no-gpu

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gpu, theano, keras

I need to train a recurrent neural network as a language model and I decided to use keras with theano backend for that. Is it better to use an ordinary PC with some graphics card instead of a "cool" server machine that can't do gpu computing? **Is there a boundary** (given perhaps by the architecture of the NN and amount of the training data) **that would separate "cpu-learnable" problems from those that can be done (in reasonable time) only by utilizing gpu?**

(I have access to an older production server in the company I work in. It has 16 cores, about 49GB of available RAM so I thought I was ready for training, now I am reading about gpu optimization theano is doing and I am thinking I am basically screwed without it.)

**Edit**

I have just come across this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.3005v3.pdf#cite.Mikolov%3A2011b), where Tomáš Mikolov states they managed to train a single-layer recurrent neural network with 1024 states in 10 days while using only 24 CPUs and no GPU.

Comment: I don't know **anybody** who trains a NN on a CPU. Your CPU might have 16 cores, but even a crappy old GPU, like the GeForce GT 430, has 96 (CUDA) cores. So the GT 430 (introduced in 2010!) will still be faster than a new 2016 Intel Xeon processor. (By all means, *don't* get a GT 430, that was just one of the oldest GPU I found on Google)

Comment: Thanks! I guess the problem could be restated as "how much of the NN training can be done on GPU"... Definitely good to know that "nobody" does that. Perfect answer for me, it makes me sad though :)

Comment: Can never be sure that 96 CUDA cores will beat 16 CPU cores, until you benchmark it with the neural network you are using. A 100-node single hidden layer NN can be easily handled on the CPU with SSE. The time it takes to transfer data to and from GPU can become the bottleneck in such simple networks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a boundary

One that would separate CPU vs GPU is memory access. If you are accessing the values from your neural network often, CPU would do better, as it has faster access to RAM. If I'm not wrong, getting the updates (SGD, RMSProp, Adagrad etc) would require that the values be accessed.

GPU would be advisable when amount of computation is larger than memory access, e.g. training a deep neural network.

> that can be done (in reasonable time) only by utilizing gpu

Unfortunately, if you are trying to solve such a hard problem, Theano would be a bad choice, as you are constrained to running on a single machine. Try other frameworks that would allow running on multiple CPU and GPU across machines, such as Microsoft CNTK or Google TensorFlow.

> thinking I am basically screwed

The difference (may be speed up or slow down) won't be that big, depending on the neural network. Plus, running the neural network computation on your machine can get in the way of your work. So you are probably better off using that extra server and making it useful.

Comment: A GPU has its own separate RAM, which is usually very fast - e.g. the Titan X has 12GB of DDR5 memory on-board.

Comment: But contents on that graphic RAM has to be transferred onto RAM for the non-Theano Python code to work on it, and it seems to be the case for the various gradient descent methods.

Comment: Yes, that is true: moving/copying things from the CPU RAM to the GPU RAM is slow. But you copy all weights and parameters to the GPU once, so you don't do that in every iteration. (At least if your model *does* fit into your GPU - if not, you are out of luck...)

Comment: Slow, well I always hear people talking about how slow it is to copy data back and forth from CPU and GPU. While a bad implementation doing it unnecessarily may spoil performance, please realise it isn't slow at all. A modern card can transfer 32 Gb/s over pci, even for the Titan X that would mean it takes 300 ms to fill the graphics memory. I would say the bottleneck is usually somewhere else, for example if the data is loaded from disk.